# Why is virtualenvwrapper not working inside wing ide pro terminal?

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenvwrapper, wing-ide

Why is virtualenvwrapper commands like workon not working inside wing ide pro terminal?

```
bash: workon: command not found
```

Any other bash terminal outside wing ide pro is working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is some difference in the PATH in Wing for some reason.  If on OS X this may be solved by starting Wing from the command line so it inherits the right environment.  On other OSes I don't know why this env would differ.

If you're trying to use specific virtualenv in Wing you'll instead want to set Python Executable in Project Properties in the Project menu in Wing Pro or Wing Personal to the virtualenv's Python executable.

Or start Wing from the commandline after running workon there.

Running workon in the OS Commands tool in Wing is not going to change the environment Wing is already running in.  It only changes the environment for that one bash instance and working with Python there is going to bypass most of the IDE's features.

Comment: does not work starting Wing from command line in Linux but thanks for the response.